# cmake on raspberry: JNI not found | But JAVA_HOME is correct and files are there

Tags: linux, opencv, cmake, java-native-interface, raspberry-pi

That's increasingly frustrating.. I'm trying to build OpenCV for Java on a Raspberry Pi and that requires JNI.
When executing Cmake, it finds ANT correctly but it always says:

```
Could NOT find JNI (missing:  JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH)
```

By now I have tried at least a dozen suggestions from the web but without any success. Even tried the modified cmake file like here: https://gist.github.com/emchristiansen/6845954
The JAVA_HOME path is also correct as `ls $JAVA_HOME` leads me to the folder of Oracle's Java 8 jdk and there are the JNI files in a subfolder...
A global search finds them too.

What could be other reasons for this problem?

Big thanks in advance.

Or on a side question.. does someone happen to have a pre-build version of OpenCV from a Raspberry the could offer for download?
I only need the native library (.so) and .jar file. Would be really great!

Comment: Exact path to header `jni.h` is `$JAVA_HOME/include/jni.h`, isn't it? What version of CMake you use?

Comment: @Tsyvarev
Thank you for the response!
Yes, exactly, there a jni.h in that include folder as well as a jawt.h and a few more plus a folder named linux with a jawt_md.h and jni_md.h.
The version is the newest I can update automatically to: 2.8.9

Comment: `FindJNI.cmake` script you refer contains line `file(TO_CMAKE_PATH "$ENV{JAVA_HOME}" _JAVA_HOME)`. Add line `message(STATUS "JAVA_HOME: '$ENV{JAVA_HOME}'")` before or after it, and see, whether appropriate message is printed during configuration.

Comment: `cb@GIBA:~/src/vnc4$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.4" 2019-07-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.4+11-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.4+11-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.3, mixed mode, sharing)
/code` I don't have any include directories. I must have installed java incorrectly by installing JRE not JDK! DAMNiggit grrrr

Comment: Hope this helps the next person: Installing Jenkins, so I manually downloaded JDK11 from oracle. `sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove jdk*;sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove openjdk*; sudo apt install /home/cb/Downloads/jdk-11.0.5_linux-x64_bin.deb;sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.5/bin/java 1` and then set my java home and includes variables. viola!